# Facebook SDK IOS login issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I have followed the instruction to implement a login process to Facebook from my app:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)facebookButton:(id)sender {

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"383032031757454" andDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"user_likes", 
                                @"read_stream",
                                nil];
        [facebook authorize:permissions];
        permissions=nil;
    }    
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}
```

After login and allow permissions to the app, Safari remains opened and I have to return back to my app manually, but the sample app "Hackbook" provided with SDK, after accepting permissions and login within Safari, it dismisses Safari and returns back to the app. I want to do the same but I wasn't successful.

This is the .plist file:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your facebook app id in `info.plist` file of your iOS app?

Similar cases are in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625210/native-ios-facebook-sso-wont-return-to-app) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666684/facebook-ios-sdk-not-returning-to-my-app).
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I have modified the .plist file, but Safari returns same error. I have uploaded .plist file values.

Comment: Try once again deleting the app and cleaning the build.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily determine why it doesn't work by digging a little bit inside `Facebook.m`. Check for the method `handleOpenURL:` in `Facebook.m`.

```
    // Facebook.m
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // If the URL's structure doesn't match the structure used for Facebook authorization, abort.
    if (![[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:[self getOwnBaseUrl]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    NSString *query = [url fragment];

    // Version 3.2.3 of the Facebook app encodes the parameters in the query but
    // version 3.3 and above encode the parameters in the fragment. To support
    // both versions of the Facebook app, we try to parse the query if
    // the fragment is missing.
    if (!query) {
        query = [url query];
    }

    NSDictionary *params = [self parseURLParams:query];
```

Set a breakpoint below `NSDictionary *params = [self parseURLParams:query];` and read the content of it. You should see an error message why the login did not work.

Comment: Hi, After following the instructions to compile the libraries for ARC version, and the folder generated only includes .h files, I'm a bit lost about it to where are the .m files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the app Facebook page, did you configure the app for iOS SSO?

What OS are you using? Your code will only work for 4.2+

You didn't follow the instructions completely, your plist file is slightly wrong (I don't think this is the problem).

Comment: I'm using 5.0, so I think it must be fine. My previous plist version was exactly the same as Facebook indicates, but it doesn't work, too. Thanks.