# iOS PhoneGap/Facebook Authentication Doesn't Complete

Tags: iphone, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, facebook-authentication

I'm new to both PhoneGap and Facebook Authentication and am trying to get the simple example that was provided in the phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect git hub project to complete authentication.  I'm able to have the application run on my iPhone, when I hit the "Login" button it takes me out of my iPhone application and into Facebooks app, shows me what I'm allowing access to, and when I press Login it logs me into Facebook and doesn't return to my iPhone application from which it was launched.  Under "My Apps" when I look in my Facebook profile I can see my application has successfully been added.

What I was expecting is to be taken back to my application and for the plugin to have its login callback called with the result from logging in.  However, this is not the case.

Can anyone please provide more information on 1. How I can authenticate without having it take me into Facebook's iPhone application and 2. What I may be doing wrong with authentication that it doesn't comeback to my iPhone application to finish authentication.

I'm using my **iPhone 4 (Version 5.0)** for my development.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

this answered my question.  [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666684/facebook-ios-sdk-not-returning-to-my-app)

Specifically the "fb" prefix that needed to be added to the URL scheme in front of my facebook app id