# Facebook IOS SDK - How to know when return to app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

How i know, when the user authorize the app, or not, and the SDK goes back to my app?
Theres any event to know that?

Comment: Please check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666684/facebook-ios-sdk-not-returning-to-my-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your appdelegate

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

and you can inspect the sourceApplication.

Also in the `applicationDidBecomeActive:` remember to call `[FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];`

Answer (score 1):

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{}
```

also you have to set URL Schemes in you .plist